# Eclipse plugin activating working sets

Tags: eclipse, plugins, working-set

I'm working on plugin, that automaticaly creates working sets based on projects in given workspace. I've managed to create new working sets, but I want them to be activated by default.
How can I achieve that? Or is it possible at all from plugin level?

Comment: you might be able to start from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512093/working-set-selection-programatically-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, but doesn't solve my problem fully.